# How do we interpret the meaning of a percentile?

Tags: interpretation, quantiles

I have learned from books that "If a score is the 40th percentile, this means that it is larger than 40% of the distribution, while the other 60% of scores are greater than or equal to the score."

My question is, when that specific score equals the previous score, shouldn't we say 40% of the distribution is "less or equal" to that score, instead of "less than" that score?

For example, say there are 500 students, and they are scored from 0 to 100. Say student A gets a score of 80 and he is in the 85th percentile, which traditionally means 85 per cent of students is less than his score, and 15% is greater or equal to his score. In a specific case, let 250 higher scorer students get all equal to a score of 80. Then, student A is not higher than 85%. Or his score is not higher than the other student who also get 80. Is he?

Answer (score 1):

The overall concept of percentiles is simple. But computing a percentile is actually a bit tricky (except for the 50th percentile, the median). There are eight different methods, and with small samples (and duplicates) they can give noticeably different results. So your confusion is a sign you understand this situation!

Learn more at:

R.J. Hyndman and Y. Fan, [Sample Quantiles in Statistical Packages](https://doi.org/10.2307/2684934), The American Statistician, Vol. 50, No. 4, pp. 361-365 (1966)

N. J. Cox, [How can I calculate percentile ranks?How can I calculate plotting positions?](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/percentile-ranks-and-plotting-positions/) (scroll down to "plotting positions")

[Xycoon online calculator for quartiles](https://www.resacorp.com/quartiles.htm).  Click on "Method 1" or "Method 5"...  to get to the individual calculators and explanations.

Comment: With an even number of values, taking the median as the mean of the two middlemost values is explained to mathematicians as a convention and to non-mathematicians as a rule. Those two middle values -- say $3, 4$ in $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ -- are naturally called the _comedians_ (as remarked independently by S.M. Stigler and R. Koenker).

Comment: @NickCox. Sure taking the mean of the two middle values is just a convention, but it is a standard one, right? There aren't seven alternatives that are actually used.  I hadn't heard of co-medians, but it made me laugh. Thanks.

Comment: The comment was no more than two small jokes and indeed intended only to amuse.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the percentile in different ways with respect to *duplicate* values.

Let's choose a really simple corner case: we have 10 times the value 0.

Then the empirical c.d.f. goes from 0 to 1 at 0. There is little mathematical reason to prefer the $cdf(0)$ to be 0 or 1. One could also define it as 0.5 but that causes just as much trouble as the other two. The most common choice (and in my experience the least problematic) is to choose the upper value. i.e. all observed values would be in the 100% quantile, which begins at 0 or larger, while values strictly less than 0 have the 0% quantile.

A similar problem also exists with the median (cf. upper median, lower median).

Comment: In principle the difference between using $<$ or $\le$ is immaterial. In practice both rules are in use.  I would recommend thinking in terms of ranks and then plotting positions or percentile ranks. https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/percentile-ranks-and-plotting-positions/index.html gives some explanation and some references. Percentiles may then be calculated using some kind of interpolation rule. Note that any really general definition should be clear not only on what happens with tied values but also on the use of any weights.